# / added to top bar in vscode wsl

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I have an extremely frustrating issue, where somehow vscode is adding a "/" to the top bar and then when I go to open a WSL window, it throws errors and isn't usable...

I know for sure that this is causing the issue because at one point I had it solved it, but I don't know how I did it (the ultimate frustration) and again, not sure what I did but the problem is back.

EDIT: I found one way to reliably get past it, which was using the WSL terminal in the directory I want to open and running `code .`

Would appreciate anyone chiming in who has more insight, though..

How do I edit this default on the top bar?

(see highlighted image below)

I have tried reinstalling vscode

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: the text in the top bar you can change in the settings and is constructed from fields. Search for `window title`

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @rioV8 the solution seems to be searching for `window title`